# Forcing a figure to break a text and be placed at a specific page

Tags: floats

How can I make this image be placed at the **first** page bottom and break the dummy text?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx,mwe,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}

    \begin{figure}[!hb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to go at the bottom, don't add `h` to the allowed places.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}

    \begin{figure}[!b]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```